# How to add script to <head> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, head, script-tag

I have to inject the below given script in between  tag using javascipt.

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '1234');
fbq('track', "page");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1234&ev=page&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

I tried this,

```
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.innerHTML = "!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');fbq('init', '1234');fbq('track', "page");";
        head.appendChild(script);
```

But its not working. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the script is working? Maybe if you properly format the script you will find some flaw that render it useless. At the very least people like me will be more willing to peruse it (I would not read code formatted like this if not forced to ;-) ).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your quotes at the end near `fbq('track', \"page\");`:

```
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = "!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');fbq('init', '1234');fbq('track', \"page\");";
    head.appendChild(script);
```

Use an IDE with a syntax highlighter.

Comment: Ya, its working. If I need to  add an img tag inside a nonscript.
Like <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1234&ev=page&noscript=1"
/></noscript>. How can I do this? An element inside other element..